# "14 is no prime number iff 14 is an odd number" (true or false?)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider the proposition: "14 is no prime number iff 14 is an odd number."

First of all, I thought: Ok, 14 isn't an odd number so in this case the proposition says it should be a prime number. So the proposition is false because 14 isn't a prime number. Then I thought it's an "iff" condition. So does that imply that the premise is true (double negation) if the conclusion is false? I don't know how to approach this question.

Comment: If you have $A \iff B$, you can split it up into $A \implies B$ and $B \implies A$ both of which must be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nicholas makes reference to in a comment, a statement of the form $P\iff Q$ will be true when $P$ and $Q$ have the same truth values, whether they be both true or both false. The important thing is that they do not differ.

In your case, you have the statement, "14 is no prime number iff 14 is an odd number." You may represent this statement using propositions:

- $P:$ 14 is no prime number
- $Q:$ 14 is an odd number

You are trying to determine whether or not $P\iff Q$ is true. Well, it should be clear that $P$ is true (14 is certainly not a prime number). However, $Q$ is false (14 is definitely not an odd number). Hence, we can see that $P$ and $Q$ have different truth values; thus, $P\iff Q$ is false.